# How to create a matlab object of a specific version using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, matlab

I am trying to create an application in vb.net. During one of the step, if the user click "Launch Matlab CMD Window" Button  then a Matlab CMD window(only the Matlab CMD window, not the actually application) will be launched.

The snipe of my code is :

```
Private Sub Matlab_CMD_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Matlab_CMD.Click
      Dim Matlab As Object = CreateObject("Matlab.Application")
End Sub
```

I know it is very simple, basically just one line of code but my problem is I have different versions(3 versions of Matlab) installed on my computer for different development environment purpose. This code launches Matlab 2009b cmd window but I want it to launch Matlab 2013a cmd window. Is there a way to define a specific version of Matlab cmd window to launch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a shared ProgID `"Matlab.Application"` which let's you start any matlab version and a version specific ProgID which let's you start a specific version, for example `"Matlab.Application.8.1"` to start Matlab 2013a. Most of the ProgIDs registered by Matlab are [explained here.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introduction_brd0vd4-1.html) To get the Version of you Matlab Installation, use the `ver` command.